# How to copy a class object in C#

Tags: c#, object

As per my understanding in C#, when an object is assigned to another object of same type, its reference is copied instead of the value. So I would like to know how to assign an object to another object such that its values are copied and not referenced to the second object..

Answer (score 5):

You can see that test2.ErrorDetail is changed to "DTL2", while test1.ErrorDetail remains "DTL1".

```
    public class TestClone : ICloneable
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorDetail { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test1 = new TestClone() { IsSuccess = true, ErrorCode = "0", ErrorDetail = "DTL1" };
        var test2 = (TestClone) test1.Clone();
        test2.ErrorDetail = "DTL2";
    }
```

Comment: Uber.  However it is unclear if OP wants _deep cloning_, something not mentioned in your answer

Comment: FYI MemberwiseClone() is used for ShallowCopy and NOT deep copy, to understand deep and shallow copy in C# this is good article - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone an object instead of assigning a reference.

Comment: Ok..thanks for your quick reply..Can you tell me how to perform clone instead of the assignment obj2 = obj1;

Comment: There are number of examples on the internet. You can check this url: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cloning-objects-in-net-framework/

Comment: Well that's pretty much a given'